# UI Picker View is not displaying

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uitableview

I have added a UI Picker in my code programmatically:

```
            UIPickerView *categoryList = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 200)];  
            categoryList.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;  
            categoryList.hidden = NO;  
            categoryList.delegate = self;  

            [cell.contentView addSubview:categoryList];
```

But, its not displaying when i run it on simulator.

Comment: set to textfield inputView

Answer (score 0):

set to textField inputView

Don't add subview.

Comment: Did you mean I should add a text field there and then add it?

Comment: @Smitha : Yes. you should have to do like this.

Comment: I feel this approach has to be followed to avoid frame is not yet set properly, I could see the picker data. Its overlapping with my next cell of table. Need to fix it.

Comment: no, picker view having default width and height (same as keyboard) we can't change it

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement UIPickerViewDelegate methods for something to appear.

Delegate methods.

```
@Required
// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{

}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:   (NSInteger)component;
{
}
```

Also UIPickerViewDelegate methods for presenting your view or string in PickerView as one below :-

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

UPDATE:-

Change your pickerView frame as below

```
UIPickerView *categoryList = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x+5, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y+5, 300, 200)];
```

Comment: I have implemented all these methods too. Sorry though I did not mention it here.

Comment: @Smitha I have updated my code and you need to change frame of your pickerView as in my update I have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Though the frame is not yet set properly, I could see the picker data. Its overlapping with my next cell of table. Need to fix it.

Comment: @Smitha your welcome but don't forget to vote up and tick it as answer.

Comment: Will definitely do it once I arrive at complete solution

Comment: @Smitha okay surely but as your query your pickerView was not getting displayed so it is now after setting frame. Therefore, you query is solved. Still if anything else then do let me know. Happy to help !